# What is the opposite of "enroll"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms, negation, prefixes

*Deenroll*? *Unenroll*? I understand words like *cancel* and *resign* would work, but is there an appropriate antonym with "enroll" in it?

Comment: Which sense of "enroll"?

Comment: Does it have to be one word? Could one perhaps ["cancel or withdraw enrollment"](https://ou.edu/registrar/enrollment/cancel-or-withdraw-enrollment)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*[Disenroll](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disenroll)*, "To cancel enrolment; to remove oneself from a list" may be the word you want.

It is in [common use](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22disenroll%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2004,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en), for example as a bit of legal jargon for leaving an insurance plan:

> A member may only disenroll from an MA plan during one of the four election periods noted above. ... When the date of death is unknown, the carrier may take action to disenroll the individual on the date...

Comment: A perfectly documented answer. +1

Comment: Also, many educational institutions seem to use the term frequently with reference to courses and programs.

Comment: [disenroll](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disenroll)

Answer (score 14):

If you are talking about what to do after you enroll in a class, but want to not be enrolled anymore, then you would

> **withdraw**

from it.

Comment: Another common antonym for schooling in general is *drop out* (e.g. dropping out of high school), and people will often say they *dropped* a class in college. These are fairly colloquial, though.

Answer (score 3):

Enroll can also be used passively/transitively, e.g. you can be enrolled onto a medical register- in which sense the antonym could be "strike off".